# Integrating OLAP Reporting in my java web application

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

I need to develop OLAP Reporting in my java web application.
Which third party tool will suite the requirement.

1. I should deploy in my own server like tomcat or jboss
2. Open source or demo versions

i can find **Pentaho**, it is quit challenging to deploy it in my jboss, Pentaho tells me that my webpages source as war should be deployed in its own BI Server, to get integrated.

Please correct me if i was misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want OLAP then i strongly recommend looking at Saiku. Under the hood it's all mondrian/Pentaho technology, but has a very clever server element, rest API's and a great UI.

Comment: Thanks @Codek, I have seen SAIKU, what is my application is running in JBOSS, i think SAIKU runs in different server. If it it so should i have to run two servers. Or can i implement all the Cubes of SAIKU in my JBOSS.

Comment: Errm, by default it runs under tomcat. However check with the guys on the ##saiku channel on freenode IRC because I know they have talked about making it work on jboss - not sure if they ever did.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your OLAP server setup already and expose as XMLA service, you can try use a pure javascript UI to pivot your OLAP cubes and create reports at [webpivottable](http://webpivottable.com)

It sits on client side and not dependent to any backend.